# Commenting lines between two tags in shell

Tags: linux, awk, sed, apache-httpd

I would like to comment/uncomment to disable/enable cache between two configuration section tags in a `httpd` instance using `sed` or `awk`.

I am able to comment/uncomment lines starting with `Cache`/`Expires` keyword but that still leaves the module tag commented. How can I comment/uncomment in such a way that every line between a start and end tag is commented/uncommented through a single command.

Here is a sample cache configuration.

```
#<IfModule mod_cache.c>
#
#<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
# CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
# CacheEnable disk 
# CacheEnable disk 
# CacheEnable disk 
# CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
# CacheDirLevels 1
#</IfModule>
#
#</IfModule>

#<IfModule mod_expires.c>
#        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
#        ExpiresActive On
#        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
#        ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
#        ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 year"
#        ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
#        ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
#        ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
#        ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
#        ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
#        ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
#        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
#        ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
#        ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
#</IfModule>
```

So I would like to have a command that could comment every single line between start of tag `<IfModule mod_cache.c>` until it is closed and so goes for `<IfModule mod_expires.c>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Have the following in script to comment or uncomment the module

```
 if [ "$2" == uncomment ]; then
    sed -i "/<IfModule $1>/,/<\/IfModule>/ s/^#//" apache.conf
 elif [ "$2" == comment ]; then
    sed -i "/<IfModule $1>/,/<\/IfModule>/ s/^\(<\| \)/#\1/" apache.conf
 fi
```

Syntax to run the script:

```
sh script.sh <moduleName> <comment/uncomment>
```

Example:

```
sh script.sh mod_disk_cache.c uncomment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple state machine in `awk`. For simplicity, let's assume `mod.xml` contains:

```xml
#stuff
#
#<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
# CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
# CacheEnable disk
# CacheEnable disk
# CacheEnable disk
# CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
# CacheDirLevels 1
#</IfModule>
#
#other stuff
```

Then,

```bsh
$ cat mod.xml | awk -F'#' 'BEGIN { state = 0; } { if (/mod_disk_cache/) state = !state; if (state) print $2; else print $0; if (/\/IfModule/) state = !state; }' > umod.xml
$ cat umod.xml
#stuff
#
<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
 CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
 CacheEnable disk
 CacheEnable disk
 CacheEnable disk
 CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
 CacheDirLevels 1
</IfModule>
#
#other stuff
```

The `state` variable records when we're inside (`state == 0`) or outside (`state != 0`) the block we want to comment/uncomment.

**Note:** One thing that's important here is that the block above not contain sub-blocks that end in a `</IfModule>` because that will reset the state prematurely. If you need to support that case then the state needs to capture more. For example, consider making the state an integer that is `-1` when outside the target block, set to `0` when you enter the target block, and incremented higher when you enter a sub-block.

This command handles your original input where the `mod_cache.c` block has a nested sub-block:

```bsh
$ cat mod.xml | awk -F# 'BEGIN { state = -1; } { if (/<IfModule mod_cache\.c>/) state = 0; else if (/<IfModule .*>/) state++; if (state >= 0) print $2; else print $0; if (/<\/IfModule/) state--;}'
```

Back to the simple example, to re-comment you can do something similar, just set the output field separator (OFS) and print out a `#` before each line when `state` evaluates to true:

```bsh
$ cat umod.xml | awk -F'#' 'BEGIN { OFS=""; state = 0; } { if (/mod_disk_cache/) state = !state; if (state) print "#", $0; else print $0; if (/\/IfModule/) state = !state; }'
#stuff
#
#<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
# CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
# CacheEnable disk
# CacheEnable disk
# CacheEnable disk
# CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
# CacheDirLevels 1
#</IfModule>
#
#other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

To Uncomment we can use below command

```
awk '/#.*IfModule mod_cache.c/,/#.*IfModule mod_expires.c/{gsub("#","",$0)}1'  filename
```

To Comment

```
awk '/^<IfModule mod_cache.c/,/^<IfModule mod_expires.c/{$0="#"$0}1'  filename
```